# Redirect existing url .php to new url

Tags: apache, redirect

How to redirect existing url to new url?

Sample :
I have www.a.com/help.php

in google/yahoo :  when visitor click this link "www.a.com/help.php" on address bar automatically change be www.a.com/help.

Because in .htaccess I was rewrite www.a.com/help and this condiction is success.

The problem is how to change automatically on address bar www.a.com/help.php --> www.a.com/help

Using .htaccess or other tricks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.a.com/help");
```

That should change the addressbar.

With .htaccess you could try

redirect 301 /help.php /help

Here you can read more on [htaccess redirect](http://www.isitebuild.com/301-redirect.htm)

Comment: in .htaccess RewriteRule ^help help.php [QSA,L],
if I using header(), its syntax always looping..

Comment: Is help the same page as help.php, then you have to check which url the page got called with before the header solution to prevent looping. With htaccess, I cannot help you more as I have only done a few rewrites myself and only tried to give you directions to a page with more info.